# Tkinter app freezes when trying to restart it

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I'm trying to make a timer using tkinter. So far the code itself works and I get the popup, but the window freezes if I try to click "start" again. I have no clue what is happening, as it didn't do this yesterday. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

import os
os.system("clear")

#functions

def popup():
    time.sleep(1200) #20minutes of delay
    response = messagebox.showinfo("Time to rest!", "Look through the window to rest your eyes.")
    #Label(root, text=response).pack()
    #root.after(2000, popup)

#tkinter GUI

root = Tk()
root.title("Eye timer")
root.geometry("400x200")

myTitle = Label(root, text="A popup will tell you to rest your eyes,"
                "\n20 minutes after you click the start button.")
myTitle.pack(pady=10)

start = Button(root, text="Start", command=popup)
start.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you press the button, do you press it when you're still waiting for 20 minutes mark? Or after the 20 minutes have passed?

Comment: You should not use `sleep()` in a GUI program. It looks like you were experimenting with `after()`. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code that will do the trick:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Timer

import os
os.system("clear")

timeToWait = 1200 #in seconds

#functions
def startTimer():
    timer = Timer(timeToWait, popup)
    timer.start()

def popup():
    messagebox.showinfo("Time to rest!", "Look through the window to rest your eyes.")

#tkinter GUI

root = Tk()
root.title("Eye timer")
root.geometry("400x200")

myTitle = Label(root, text="A popup will tell you to rest your eyes,"
                "\n20 minutes after you click the start button.")
myTitle.pack(pady=10)

start = Button(root, text="Start", command = startTimer)
start.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Your problem was that you freeze your app with the sleep function for 20 minutes.
*Never use sleep function inside your GUI!* It will result in weird behavior.

I have implemented threading into your code.

Every time you press the start button `Timer` object will be created and started.
This object takes two parameters

1. Time after which it will execute the target function.
2. Target function.

This way you will achieve what you want and the GUI won't freeze!

Comment: Didn't know about threading. This makes much more sense, thanks!

Comment: It is a way to go when building apps and GUIs. 100% check it out it will help you a lot in the future! No problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

the program is freezed for 20 minutes.

a fix:

````
import threading

start = Button(root, text="Start", command=threading.Thread(target=popup).start())```
````

Comment: Your code will start the thread immediately without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go with tkinter is to use `root.after()`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

#functions
popup_running = False

def popup():
    global popup_running
    response = messagebox.showinfo("Time to rest!", "Look through the window to rest your eyes.")
    popup_running = False

def start_popup():
    global popup_running
    if popup_running:
        return
    popup_running = True
    root.after(20 * 60 * 1000, popup)

#tkinter GUI

root = Tk()
root.title("Eye timer")
root.geometry("400x200")

myTitle = Label(root, text="A popup will tell you to rest your eyes,"
                "\n20 minutes after you click the start button.")
myTitle.pack(pady=10)

start = Button(root, text="Start", command=start_popup)
start.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```